# External jar file for lucene in not working

Tags: java, lucene

I have added External jar files for lucene like this image:

[image: external jar files]

But still its giving errors

[image: Import errors]

If i click on the error it shows

> import org.apache.lucene.queryParser can not be resolved

What can I do now to solve this error.

Comment: These package names are case sensitive. Please use lower-case letters.

Comment: I used lower case but still not working

Comment: It should (if you add `.*` after it)

Comment: you said it  "import org.apache.lucene.search.hit.*;" but still error

Comment: Sedat you comment is unclear

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using code that was made for an older version of Lucene (pre 3.0.0).

The whole queryparser has been moved into another package.
Please see this [migration documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html), especially: *LUCENE-3283: Query parsers moved to separate module*.

[search.hit](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Hit.html) and [search.hits](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Hits.html) are both deprecated for a long time now. Please refer to old documentation on what to replace them with.